# What's the difference between an E and E^ for some Enum E? (C++/CLI)

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Suppose I defined an enum E as follows:

```
#pragma managed

namespace MyNamespace
{
  public enum class E
  {
    X = 0,
    Y = 1,
    Z = 2
  };
}
```

what is the difference between the following two method signatures?

```
#pragma managed

namespace MyNameSpace
{
  public MyClass
  {
      public void method1(E an_enum) {}

      public void method2(E^ an_enum) {}
   };
}
```

I'm trying to understand the implications between using E vs. E^.
Thanks.

Comment: method2() is declared wrong, it's argument is boxed.  Required to turn a value type like E into a ^ reference.  Particularly troublesome to public methods that are exposed to other languages, the argument type becomes System::ValueType instead of E.  Syntax to intentionally box was meant as a feature, but they made it too universal.

Answer (score 0):

The 'hat' operator is C++/CLI version of a pointer in short.
instead of the value being passed along it passes the location of the object in memory.
Its behaves as a pointer but allows .Net to track your object. if it notices the object is no longer tracked, the garbage collector will delete the object.

More on the 'hat' operator:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/handle-to-object-operator-hat-cpp-component-extensions?view=vs-2019